# codeigniter mysql updating penalties everynow and then

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have this at my model, I want to update the price everynow and then, I want that everytime I open the controller it will add up 100 to the Penalty, how do I do that? what is wrong with my query? Probably because of the update right? I dont know plz help! If I put 200 at 'Penalty' + 200 it will go for 200 and then if I put 100 it puts 100 again

```
public function addPenalty(){
    $data = array(
        'Penalty' => 'Penalty' + 100
        );
    $this->db->where('Active',1);
    $query = $this->db->update('tbl_client_penalties',$data);
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Retrieve the value of `Penalty` and then add `100` to it and then update the table using the updated value.

Comment: what is Penalty in `Penalty' + 100` ?

Comment: i just saw that in the query i thought it was corret! is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$this->db->set('Penalty', 'Penalty + '.100, FALSE);
$this->db->where('Active',1);
$this->db->update('tbl_client_penalties');
```

for more information check the [document](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$dbdata["Penalty"] = "Penalty + 100";
$this->db->update("tbl_client_penalties", $dbdata, array('Active' => 1));
```